# how to zip two different file extension

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In this example I successfully ssh into my remote server and zip files in the data directory that only have .jtl extensions. I would now like to also include files with a .log extension. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
( ssh -nq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -i $PEM_PATH/$PEM_FILE $USER@${hosts[$i]} -p $REMOTE_PORT \
    zip -j -r $REMOTE_HOME/$DATETIME-$i-jtls.zip $REMOTE_HOME/data/*.jtl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append files and file matches to the end of the `zip` command to add more files:

```
zip -j -r ... /data/*.jtl /data/*.log ...
```

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip